# App content post on Facebook not opening app upon clicking post

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking, applinks

I'm having some issues with Facebook App Links on Android. Problem: clicking a Facebook post that contains a URL to my app's content opens the webpage of the content in Facebook's mobile "browser" instead of deep linking into my Android app.

**Web page meta data** (values modified for privacy):

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="983094809459723"><meta 
property="og:title" content="Manchester Orchestra"><meta property="og:image" content="https://i.scdn.co/image/aj0293jfalskdfj0293asd"><meta property="og:url" content="https://api.intabc.com/client/redirect/artist/09faslk9-a0d7-3bed-97c5-0923fjlasd9f0"><meta property="al:android:url" content="https://api.intabc.com/client/redirect/artist/09faslk9-a0d7-3bed-97c5-0923fjlasd9f0"><meta property="al:ios:url" content="abc-int://artist?artist_id=09faslk9-a0d7-3bed-97c5-0923faesd9f0"><meta property="al:android:package" content="com.intabc.mobile"><meta property="al:android:app_name" content="ABC - Integration"><meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="ABC - Integration">
```

**Deep link intent filter**

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data
        android:scheme="https"
        android:host="api.intabc.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/client/redirect/artist"/>
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data
        android:scheme="abc-int"
        android:host="artist"/>
</intent-filter>
```

**Things I've tried**:

a) Copy-pasted my content's URL posted to Facebook into a Chrome tab. This correctly redirects to my Android app.

b) Added "al:android:url", "al:android:package", "al:android:app_name", "og:url", and "al:web:should_fallback" (false) meta properties to all of my content web pages, where "og:url" and "al:android:url" contain the same value tested in a).

Do I need to register my app for Facebook App Links? /shrug

I would greatly appreciate any ideas on what might be the issue.

Comment: You should not need to register your app. If configured properly, facebook should open your app. Do you have any code of your intent filter or page header that you can share?

Comment: @clayjones94 Added relevant code

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using an Android App Link in the meta tag below:

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="https://api.intabc.com/client/redirect/artist/09faslk9-a0d7-3bed-97c5-0923fjlasd9f0">
```

Facebook only supports URI scheme deep linking from their native app. Hence, if the url uses `https` or `http` then the link is going to be handled by the Facebook browser.

### Option 1

Change your `al:android:url` to use your Android app's URI scheme, similar to what you did in iOS. This will open your app if installed or fallback to your web URL if `al:web:should_fallback` is set to `true`

### Option 2 (Best option)

Let [Branch](http://branch.io) (I work there) handle your deep linking. It's just easier that way.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I changed my `al:android:url` from an HTTP URL ("https://api.intabc.com/client/redirect/artist/...") to a mobile URI ("abc-int://artist?artist_id=09faslk9-a0d7-3bed-97c5-0923fjlasd9f0"), and Facebook still did not redirect to my app. Do you have a link to any Facebook documentation stating that Facebook doesn't support HTTP URL schemes for deep linking?

Note: when I copy-paste the same URI to a mobile Chrome tab, Chrome correctly redirects to my app. This leads me to believe that Facebook is doing something that's preventing the deep link.

Comment: According to Facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content): "The sharesample URI scheme represents your unique custom scheme." You should also check [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android) about adding the Facebook App Links SDK to handle app links.

Comment: My scheme appears to be set correctly, and my app's build.gradle file contains the App Links dependency: `'com.facebook.android:facebook-applinks:4.27.0'`. Still investigating...

Comment: Just tried adding "al:web:should_fallback" and setting it to false... still no luck.